# Linear Correlation of 1 Leaving Residual Values in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, line, data-modeling, correlation, data-fitting

I have a set of data, X and Y, which I wish to fit a line to, get the R and R^2 values for, and also graph the residuals from the difference between the best fit line values and the actual data. Here's my MATLAB code that does this:

```
maxx = max(X); minx = min(X);
fitx = minx:maxx / 1000:maxx;
coeff = polyfit(X,Y,1);
fity = polyval(coeff,fitx);

temp = corrcoef(X,Y); 
R = temp(2); R_squared = R^2;

ysub = polyval(coeff,X); 
residuals = Y - ysub;

subplot(1,2,1);
plot(X,Y,'+',fitx,fity,'r')
xlabel(['R = ' num2str(R) '; R^2 = ' num2str(R_squared)]);

subplot(1,2,2);
bar(residuals);
```

So I tested it on what *should* be an "ideal" dataset that could fit a line perfectly, and sure enough, I get an R and an R^2 value of 1, and my first plot looks fine, but my residuals are ranging from 7000 to -3000. Shouldn't my residuals be 0 if my R values are 1?

What am I misunderstanding here?

Here is the sample dataset:

```
X = [100 200 290 390 480 580 670 760 860 950]
Y = 1.0e+07 * [0.2429 0.4929 0.7183 0.9689 1.1946 1.4453 1.6711 1.8968 2.1477 2.3735]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to diagnose with a sample dataset.

At a guess, the problem is that your first line should be:

```
maxx = max(X); minx = min(X);
```

The way you had it `minx=min(Y)` distorts your fitx and fity values

Edit:

Thank you for submitting the sample data.  What you are seeing now is only rounding errors.  Your R isn't actually 1, it's just really close.  Try:

```
 R-1
```

The result for your data is -1.0301e-07, indicating that the correlation isn't quite perfect.  If R was exactly 1, then you are correct that the residuals would be zero.  Your residuals are pretty small given the size of your data ( < 0.3% for the first point and at least 10x smaller for the rest) and are consistent with your measured correlation coefficient.

I think everything is working correctly.

Comment: Whoops! That was just an error in transcribing. My actual code starts by taking the min and max of X only. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: I also added the sample dataset to the question.